# generate unique id on registration form jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to generate a unique code (like: xxxxxxxxxxx xx) onsubmit form.
after completing the information in the registration form,the application will generate a unique code in an ouput on an other form.

Comment: I would suggest use java and not javascript for generating unique id, since you area already using jsp.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's common practice to perform this kind of logic server-side. Is there a particular reason for your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript math.random() is your most straight choice :

```
var random = (Math.random()).toString().split('.')[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some already answered posts in response to your query -

[Generate unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060428/generate-unique-id)

or you can refer here - 
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56

Comment: i know that, i was going to suggest to the person to use java and not javascript.